# cocoa app crashs when operating on one childwindow

Tags: cocoa, debugging, crash-reports

I'm working on an issue as the title describes. After crash, I only get a crash log posted below. As my code is not listed in the stack list, I have not idea how to find the cause of the crash, is there any way to set some logging to see what happened?

Thank you!

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x934eed4b objc_msgSend + 27
1 com.apple.AppKit 0x95aecc93 __-NSWindow release_block_invoke_1 + 42
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x939fee85 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x93a00e15 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 260
4 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x9b408d53 __CFRunLoopRun + 2003
5 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x9b4081ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 332
6 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x9b408098 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 120
7 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x9ab32487 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 318
8 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x9ab39dc3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 381
9 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x9ab39c32 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
10 com.apple.AppKit 0x953d08ec _DPSNextEvent + 678
11 com.apple.AppKit 0x953d0159 -NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue: + 113
12 com.apple.AppKit 0x953cc4cb -NSApplication run + 904
13 com.apple.AppKit 0x9565fb54 NSApplicationMain + 1054
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is this when you're trying to attach a child window?

Comment: Hi, actually I'm not sure what is happening, the child window sends a job to server then close. and the crash happens. I guess this is caused by a premature release or over-release. We are now using NSZombieEnabled for more info about the crash. However, the crash rarely happens, we can not reproduce it now.

Comment: More info, the window is opened by another thread.

Comment: Well there you go. Never interact with UI elements on a different thread. AppKit, for the most part, is not thread-safe. Dispatch to the main thread before interacting with your window.